# How do I handle a closing brace in a 'character scanning' macro?

Tags: macros, braces, parameters

### Problem

I need to define a command that grabs all numerical digits following it and leaves the rest alone. Eventually I came up with this:

### First Solution

```
\RequirePackage{xstring} % for \IfInteger

\newcommand*{\num}{%
    \def\@tmpnum{}%
    \@num%
}

\newcommand*{\@num}[1]{%
    \IfInteger{#1}{%
        \edef\@tmpnum{\@tmpnum#1}\@num%
    }{%
        [I saw the number \@tmpnum!]#1%
    }%
}
```

The `\@num` macro scans ahead by recursively calling itself. Every digit it encounters is appended to `\@tmpnum`. The first non-digit it sees ends the sequence and is put back.

It works as intended in simple cases:

```
\num1234...
```

outputs:

```
[I saw the number 1234!]...
```

### How to Handle `\par` - Second Solution

It soon occurred to me that `\IfInteger` can't handle a `\par`, so... second solution:

```
\newcommand{\@num}[1]{%
    \def\@end{%
        [I saw the number \@tmpnum!]#1%
    }%
    \ifdefequal{#1}{\par}\@end{%
        \IfInteger{#1}{%
            \edef\@tmpnum{\@tmpnum#1}\@num%
        }\@end%
    }%
}
```

### How to Handle a Closing Brace?

This one I can't figure out. What if I want to accept something like this:

```
\emph{\num42}
```

Whatever I try, I get some error about having too many closing braces. I guess I'm putting it back when it was already scanned. But that doesn't really help me.

- Can I test for a closing brace? Is there some other way to handle this?
- Are other such problems waiting for me?

Comment: What is the exact specification of the _number_ that the macro should grab? It is a number with explicit digits and the next non-digit stops the number? Or is the number anything that TeX accepts as number? What about the case, that a number is not given? What is the purpose of the number grabbing?

Comment: The purpose is to grab a 1-based index. I really only need explicit simple positive integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To scan a character at a time you need to use `\futurelet` (or its LaTeX wrapper `\@ifnextchar`) not a macro argument `#1` then it is safe for `{}`. But for numbers I would just do this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\num{\afterassignment\xnum\count@}


\def\xnum{the number was [\the\count@]}

\num44

\emph{\num99}

\end{document}
```

---

There is nothing special about `\count@` here. It is just a handy scratch count register that is declared in LaTeX and plain. You could go `\newcount\mycount` and then use `\mycount` instead. The point is that when assigning a value to a count register TeX automatically parses for a number and puts the value in the register. `\afterassignment` then gives you a hook to gain control after the assignment has been done and do something with the value.

Comment: Good plan: I was thinking `\futurelet` with charcode detection, but as you say `\afterassignment` is by far the cleanest way here!

Comment: Very elegant! Thanks also for pointing me to `\futurelet`, which I'll have to check out regardless. But I guess the trick here is `\count@`. Could you explain what it does exactly (in the answer, maybe)? This is not something I can Google for.

Comment: @JosephWright This method gobbles spaces and expands tokens afterwards in some situations and it breaks, if there is no number.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek You can deal with the no-number problem by adding a `0` in the definition of `\num`. From the question, it's not clear what the behaviour should be for spaces, implicit tokens, _etc._

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek yes I thought about putting a 0 in but wasn't sure if that was the right thing to do `0-1` wouldn't work for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would work with e-TeX if you use `\numexpr`.

Comment: I added some notes re count@ to the answer.

Comment: @JosephWright ooh very modern for me:-) but you wouldn't be able to drop in the `\relax` so the expression would terminate wherever so `\num 3 + 2` would return 5, which might not be what is wanted.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the `\count@` info. About the 'no number' issue. In this case, I want to handle that separately. The number is actually a 1-based index. And it may be used inside an arithmetic equation, so I really don't want it to do any complicated parsing. :-) Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

I do not know the purpose and format of the "number". There are many variants what can be considered a number:

1. Explicit number consisting of digits `0` up to `9`.
2. TeX number, that includes count registers, internal numbers given by primitives (`\inputlineno`, `\value{page}`, `\numexpr`), even dimensions (`\textwidth`) can be interpreted as numbers.

This solution assumes an explicit number, because the questions speaks of "grabbing numerical digits". Also the tokens afterwords should be kept
and not removed. When scanning a number TeX sometimes gobbles a space or expands the tokens afterwards in some situations.

The test relies on `\futurelet` to inspect the next token.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\num}{%
    \let\@tmpnum\@empty
    \futurelet\@tmptok\scan@getnum
}
\newcommand*{\scan@getnum}{%
  \let\scan@next\scan@addnum
  \ifx\@tmptok0%
  \else\ifx\@tmptok1%
  \else\ifx\@tmptok2%
  \else\ifx\@tmptok3%
  \else\ifx\@tmptok4%
  \else\ifx\@tmptok5%
  \else\ifx\@tmptok6%
  \else\ifx\@tmptok7%
  \else\ifx\@tmptok8%
  \else\ifx\@tmptok9%
  \else
    \def\scan@next{%
      [I saw the number \@tmpnum!]%
    }%
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
  \scan@next
}
\newcommand*{\scan@addnum}[1]{%
  \edef\@tmpnum{\@tmpnum#1}%
  \futurelet\@tmptok\scan@getnum
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\num1234...

\num56 78 with spaces

\num9\par

\emph{\num42}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks! Very instructive! (To be honest I never even considered the issue of gobbling spaces. One problem at a time. :-) )

Comment: I see you have two different solutions in one code block now. Are they semantically equivalent? (Also, might want to separate them into two blocks?)

Comment: @mhelvens Yes, they are equivalent. I have forgot to delete the second code block -- a drawback of the GUI with a thumbnail sized editor window :-(

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered a feature of [`etextools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etextools), based on `\futurelet`, that seems to be made for this purpose:

```
\newcommand*{\num}{%
    \futuredef[0123456789]{\@nn}{[I saw the number \@nn!]}%
}
```

`\futuredef` takes a list of tokens that it accepts and it stops scanning when it sees anything else.